# Get 80040153 error with Visual Studio 2019 SSIS project when targeting SQLServer 2019

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2019

Visual Studio Community 2019 16.8.1, SQL Server 2019

I created a new SSIS project in VS 2019. Then I created a `Connection Manager` and successfully Tested the connection against the database.

When executing a `SQL Task` with a simple `query` I get this error:

`[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "" failed with the following error: "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0EB5013B-538B-456B-AF1B-96DD1004026B} failed due to the following error: 80040153 Invalid value for registry (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040153 (REGDB_E_INVALIDVALUE)).". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.`

If I open a SSIS project created with Visual Studio 2017 and set up an identical `Connection Manager`, `Execute SQL Task` and `query` it successfully runs.

Since the `query` works with the VS 2017 SSIS project I believe the system is configured correctly.

I have unistalled and re-installed the `SQL Server Integration Serives Projects` extension in Visual Studio and then deleted and recreated the SSIS project.

In the `.dtproj` file there is a  entry.

```
  <Configurations>
    <Configuration>
      <Name>Development</Name>
      <Options>
        <OutputPath>bin</OutputPath>
        <ConnectionMappings />
        <ConnectionProviderMappings />
        <ConnectionSecurityMappings />
        <DatabaseStorageLocations />
        <TargetServerVersion>SQLServer2017</TargetServerVersion>
        <AzureMode>false</AzureMode>
        <LinkedAzureTenantId />
        <LinkedAzureAccountId />
        <LinkedAzureSSISIR />
        <LinkedAzureStorage />
        <RemoteExecutionFolder />
        <ParameterConfigurationValues>
          <ConfigurationSetting>
            <Id>LastModifiedTime</Id>
            <Name>LastModifiedTime</Name>
            <Value xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2019-07-04T21:20:58.4351661Z</Value>
          </ConfigurationSetting>
        </ParameterConfigurationValues>
      </Options>
    </Configuration>
  </Configurations>
```

In the VS 2017 SSIS project it is set to `SQLServer2017`.  In the VS 2019 SSIS project `SQLServer2019`.  If I target `2017` in the VS 2019 SSIS project the error clears.

From SSMS I ran the query  `SELECT @@VERSION` and it reports:

`Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4517790) - 15.0.2070.41 (X64) Oct 28 2019 19:56:59   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 18363: ) (Hypervisor)`

Why does targeting `SQLServer2019` throw the error but targeting `SQLServer2017` runs successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Command Prompt you need to run `regsvr32 SQLTaskConnections.dll` to register the DLL. This will allow targeting of `SQLServer2019` in the .dtproj file.